# In R, how do you have colMedians ignore 1 row entries? (in grouped/split data)

Tags: r, split, median, lapply

I'm working with the miscTools package and want to utilize colMedians. I split my data up into many groups and it ends up that some of the those groups only have one row. Therefore, colMedians says "argument 'x' must be numeric". Is there a way to have colMedians ignore those groups (or have those values regurgitated) but calculate medians of Stage.Duration for the groups that do have more than one row?

Data looks like so:

```
Opportunity.Name       Stage.Duration       Probability
      Bob                 10                   20
      Bob                 20                   50
      Bob                 76                   90
      Jon                 50                   80
      Jon                 34                   50
      Jon                 23                   100

gdata <- split(data, Opportunity.Name)
gdata$`Bob`
Opportunity.Name       Stage.Duration       Probability
      Bob                 10                   20
      Bob                 20                   50
      Bob                 76                   90          
seven <- lapply(gdata, function(x){x[x$Probability>=70,]})
seven
Opportunity.Name       Stage.Duration       Probability
      Bob                 76                   90        

med<-sapply(seven, function(x) colMedians(x[,c("Stage.Duration", "Probability")]))
```

note: the "med" code calculates medians for Stage.Duration and Probability, but I only want Stage.Duration, I just needed two columns to run this specific code and didn't know how else to run a similar function. This code works for colMeans.

Comment: Then don't subset with both columns... use `colMedians(x[, 'Probability', drop=FALSE])`... or just use the `median` function directly...

Comment: I would just use `drop=FALSE`

Comment: I tried the above code with colMeans and it changes some of my data (I suspect because of drop=FALSE). Ultimately, I need to import it back into Excel so keeping some sort of continuity with formatting would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When subsetting arrays or matrices using brackets `[ ]`,  results are normally coerced into smaller dimensional objects if they fit.   To turn this behavior off, there is a flag named `drop`:

```
 # Sample Matrix
 M <- matrix(1:20, ncol=5)

 # Gets coerced to a single vector:
 colMeans(M[3, ])
   #  Error in colMeans(M[3, ]) : 
   #    'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

 # Remains two-dimensional
 colMeans(M[3, , drop=FALSE])
    # [1]  3  7 11 15 19
```

Comment: drop = FALSE is taking into account the values that I filtered out with lapply. Is there a way to make sure drop=FALSE acknowledges those filtered values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring.  Perhaps you could post a reproducible example?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how I could be able to give you an example (sorry, I'm new :( ) but ultimately, when I apply drop=FALSE, it will calculate the median of the original dataset (before I filtered out probability greater than or equal to 70%). It will not calculate the trimmed data "seven" but gdata$'Bob'